# Defining a variable as a method that was the caller of the method that contains the variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, methods

This is kind of hard to explain in a single sentence as a title, but basically I'm working on a TypeScript file that is causing errors. [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=7&module=1#) is a TypeScript playground with code simulating the problem; the code is basically the same in JS as it is TS.

Here is the code outside of the TS playground:

```
const A = (class A {
    b() {
        const d = this.d;
        d();
    }
    d() {
        const b = this.b;
    }
})
new A().b()
```

Here is the Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'b' of undefined
    at d (eval at <anonymous> (main-3.js:1241), <anonymous>:8:24)
    at A.b (eval at <anonymous> (main-3.js:1241), <anonymous>:5:9)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (main-3.js:1241), <anonymous>:11:9)
    at main-3.js:1241
```

Any help as to how to avoid this while maintaining the variable declaration alias would be useful.

Thank you!

Comment: Your link is just to the playground, it's not a code share link. Please include the TypeScript in your question directly anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Call the `d()` method with `this.d()` and `this` will be defined in that method:

```js
const A = class {
    b() {
        const d = this.d;
        this.d();
    }
    d() {
        const b = this.b;
        console.log(b);
    }
};

new A().b();
```

Comment: Is there any way of doing this by calling the "d" variable as the function rather than use the accessor on "this"?

Comment: @Tartarus13 Not if you want to use `this` inside it. @qxg provided a rather hacky way of making it work, but I would discourage using arrow functions for methods. You would basically be abusing that principle just to achieve this weird goal of calling it as a standalone variable.

Comment: @Tartarus13: `const b = this.b.bind(this)` / `const b = () => this.b()`

Answer (score 0):

It must be a dup, but just use arrow function

```
const A = (class A {
    b = () => {
        const d = this.d;
        d();
    }
    d = () => {
        const b = this.b;
    }
})
new A().b()
```

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the enclosing lexical scope is used;

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Christian is 100% correct. Explanation for you: the this variable will be undefined because of the `Javascript this-binding`.
For e.g. this code here could also work:

```
const A = class {
b() {
    const d = this.d;
    d.call(this); // Here we bind the this variable to the Class itself.
}
d() {
    const b = this.b;
    console.log("HERE WE GO!");
}
};

new A().b();
```

As a recommendation to you check out the "You don't know JS" book series. Here is the Chapter for the `this` variable: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md